# Find lowest value matched from an Index/Match of an array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, vlookup, min, google-query-language

[Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jm1UubMwHpPaj4aFNMN_mdTWSNdH9LP8_wvOEZnemv0/edit?usp=sharing)

Current formula not returning values as desired:

`=IFERROR(ifNA(min(arrayformula(index(D2:I2, match(INDEX(FLATTEN(split(A2, ", ", FALSE)&" "&TRANSPOSE(split(B2, ", ", FALSE)))), D$1:I$1, 0)))), "Role not at Facility"), "")`

Column A contains a comma separated list of locations, Column B is a list of roles.

I want to check all combinations of a single location to a single role. `arrayformula(FLATTEN(split(A2, ", ", FALSE)&" "&TRANSPOSE(split(B2, ", ", FALSE))))` is giving me an array of all combinations well enough.

I was hoping there was a way to feed that array into an index/match that would return all the matching values into an array so I could wrap that in a min() and get the lowest value of the array as my ultimate goal.

My sample sheet shows some of the problems I'm having, most obviously that the only location/role combo that gets evaluated is the first one.

Current state (formula in % Credentialed column)

| Location Credentialing For | Role Credentialing For | % Credentialed | VALLEY ROLE 1 | VALLEY ROLE 2 | VALLEY ROLE 3 | MISSION ROLE 1 | MISSION ROLE 3 | RIVER ROLE 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MISSION, RIVER | ROLE 1, ROLE 3 | 100.00% | 88.24% | 94.74% | 94.74% | 100.00% | 88.24% | 88.24% |
| MISSION, VALLEY, RIVER | ROLE 2 | Role not at Facility | 15.00% | 20.00% | 60.00% | 80.00% | 100.00% | 16.00% |
| VALLEY, MISSION | ROLE 2, ROLE 1 | 88.00% | 100.00% | 88.00% | 20.00% | 15.00% | 20.00% | 50.00% |

Desired return

| Location Credentialing For | Role Credentialing For | % Credentialed | VALLEY ROLE 1 | VALLEY ROLE 2 | VALLEY ROLE 3 | MISSION ROLE 1 | MISSION ROLE 3 | RIVER ROLE 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MISSION, RIVER | ROLE 1, ROLE 3 | 88.25% | 88.24% | 94.74% | 94.74% | 100.00% | 88.24% | 88.24% |
| MISSION, VALLEY, RIVER | ROLE 2 | 16.00% | 15.00% | 20.00% | 60.00% | 80.00% | 100.00% | 16.00% |
| VALLEY, MISSION | ROLE 2, ROLE 1 | 15.00% | 100.00% | 88.00% | 20.00% | 15.00% | 20.00% | 50.00% |

Comment: why C2 is 100% and not 88.24% if you are after min value?

Comment: Totally could have made double checked that example better. You're right, the desired result for C2 would bee 88.25%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FLATTEN(INDEX(QUERY(IFNA(VLOOKUP(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(
 ROW(A2:A5)&"×"&ROW(A2:A5)&SPLIT(A2:A5, ", ", )))&" "&
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ", )&"×"&ROW(B2:B5))), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where Col1=Col3 
    and not Col2 matches '^\d+ .*|.* $' 
    and Col1 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col3"), SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(A2:A5)&D1:I1&"×"&D2:I5), "×"), 2, 0)), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 "min(Col"&ROW(A2:A5)-(ROW(A2)-1)&")")), 2))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet with step by step formula explanation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kbs2xw3_AlGiT0z9adDERL1tv_Eq7x-ddbSwaH7lejo/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Wow. Okay. Thank you, I don't think I could have gotten to this answer on my own. Would you be able to explain what it's doing? It does absolute work in the example sheet, and this is something that I can edit to work with my full data set but I'm not sure I understand why it works.

Comment: @NomadicPeach sure, heres the full explanation: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kbs2xw3_AlGiT0z9adDERL1tv_Eq7x-ddbSwaH7lejo/edit#gid=0

Comment: That was very helpful and I was able to use this in a larger data set. Is there any way to not have every value recalculate when a role or location is changed? If row three adds a second role, everything recalculates and after fifty rows, i find this solution times out.

Comment: @NomadicPeach recalculation of formulae cant be stopped. the best I can think of is to wrap the whole formula into IF statement and add some checkbox which will act like a switch eg. checked = formula runs / unchecked = formula is disabled

Comment: I added an extra answer for a non-array return that I ended up using. Would not have gotten there without all your help and the full explanation you shared. I ended up making a copy of your explanation sheet to really dig into how the data was returning and it ended up giving inspiration to solve several more problems. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the above answer as the official answer but adding that, if an array result is not desired, like for a large enough dataset that is regularly updated and would suffer like this, I used the above answer to par down to the below that also works:

```
=min(ArrayFormula(IFNA(ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(FLATTEN(ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(flatten(SPLIT(A2, ", ", )))&" "&Transpose(SPLIT(B2, ", ", )))), ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ArrayFormula(D1:I1&"×"&D2:I2)), "×")), 2, 0)))))
```

Please see player0's answer for the array return version of the above.